# ADODB.Recordset.Update returns an error after upgrading from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012, ado

I recently received access to SQL Server 2012 in order to test out our current web applications to identify any issues that may appear when upgrading our current SQL Server 2008 machines.

One of our systems is a third party vendor solution that uses ODBC connections and ADO RecordSet objects for database communication.

When I connected this applications to SQL Server 2012, I started to receive the following error:

> Query-based update failed because the row to update could not be found

I've worked with our DBAs to get Trace files from the same code process on both SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2012 and everything looks exactly the same. I've also made sure the data exists in the database before the code is executed. Setting the database to SQL Server 2008 compatibility also didn't work.

Unfortunately we don't have the ability to get the source code of the application modified to make any code changes. The system is vastly out of date and I believe the support contract has run out as well.

As a result, I expect we'll have to stick with SQL Server 2008, but I'm hoping someone will have ideas as to why SQL Server 2012 might have caused the ADO `RecordSet.Update()` method to behave differently.

The code is an absolute mess, but here's the gist of the method that I've been able to extract out of the DLL files:

```
private void update(ADODB.Connection xConn)
{
    ADODB.Recordset recordset = new RecordsetClass();

    //simplified query, it's actually auto-generated based on configuration values
    string query = "SELECT ID, DateModified, DateCreated FROM table WHERE ID = 1";

    recordset.Open(query, xConn, CursorTypeEnum.adOpenForwardOnly, LockTypeEnum.adLockOptimistic, Convert.ToInt32(CommandTypeEnum.adCmdText));
    try
    {
        if (recordset.EOF)
        {
            throw new Exception("Invalid/missing policy record for id " + id.ToString());
        }

        recordset.Fields["DateModified"].Value = value1;
        recordset.Fields["DateCreated"].Value = value2;
        //Other column updates          

        if (!HasOpenTransaction)
        {
            xConn.BeginTrans();
        }

        try
        {
            //Throws the exception with SQL2012
            recordset.Update(Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

            if (HasOpenTransaction)
            {
                xConn.CommitTrans();
                flag2 = true;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (HasOpenTransaction && !flag2)
            {
                xConn.RollbackTrans();
            }
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        recordset.Close();
    }
}
```

---

EDIT:
I finally moved on to the next web application that uses Linq to SQL with DBML data files. It appears to have a similar issue. When we pull down a record, update it and then call `db.SubmitChanges()`, an exception is thrown with the following message:

> Row not found or changed

Comment: Have you tried taking the actual generated query and running it in SSMS?

Comment: @jac We did pull the query out of SQL Profiler and run it through SSMS and it ran fine. The record was correctly updated with the specified values. The query we retrieved ended up executing sp_prepexec with the query string.

Comment: Is the extra space inside of the quotes intentional for "DateCreated ", or is it just typo?

Comment: @tgolisch - That is a typo. I'll correct it.

Comment: I know you look for answer but I have a question ...so what is the difference between `ADODB.Recordset` and `ADO.NET`

Comment: @meda I suggest you post a new question.

Comment: do you know the answer @RajMore I was just wondering ... no need for question bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem in the server's default connection settings.

When SQL Server 2012 was installed on the new hardware, `NO COUNT`, `QUOTED IDENTIFIER` and `ANSI NULL Default On` were enabled as default connection settings. `NO COUNT` was causing problems for the ADO and Linq to SQL data access models. Once that default option was removed, everything started working fine.

So this isn't really an ADO or SQL Server 2012 upgrade issue, this is something that might occur on any new SQL Server install.

As a side note, a third system I tested that uses Entity Framework did not show any issues with `NO COUNT` enabled and ran normally.